# Wordpress: create a custom home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a website using wordpress, but I want my website to have a customized home page, created by me, completely different from the theme of the site, and then link the wordpress pages directly from my page.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?
Can I simply create the page, and link the other created with the wordpress panel, without breaking everything?

Answer (score 5):

According to [official WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy):

If a visitor goes to your home page at http://example.com/blog/, the following happens:

1. WordPress first determines whether it has a static front page. If a static front page has been set, then WordPress loads that page according to the page template hierarchy.
2. If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a template file called **home.php** and uses it to generate the requested page.
3. If home.php is missing, WordPress looks for a file called index.php in the active theme's directory, and uses that template to generate the page.

Therefore you just need to create a **home.php** template and place it with the other theme (which so ever theme you will use) templates and WordPress will automatically start using home.php template for the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the default page.php template file and call it `front-page.php`. Change the configuration at the top of that file. Now create a new page called home.

Go to Administration > Settings > Reading panel and set a static front page.

For more help check this link on the Wordpress website:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: You don't need to attach the template to the home page.  If you've assigned the page as the static home page in Settings->Reading then Wordpress will automatically use the template `front-page.php` for it.

Comment: No worries - it took me ages to realise that, thought it was worth explicitly adding to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you create HTML off your home page first than this is easy for you

First Create a file Like this "template-home.php" in your theme.

Now in "template-home.php" First you must write these lines at the top of the page

```
<?php
/* ==========
  Template Name: Home
  ========== */
?>
```

After that add your header.php and footer.php like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

     // Your Content is here

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now your Whole HTML is work between in Header and Footer

Then Go to your Admin Panel

Go to Pages > add new

and create a page named "Home"

**NOTE:** When you create a page Please Select a Template of Home and "Publish" it.

Then go to Settings > Reading and select "A static page (select below)" radio button, then a drop down is active and select your "Home" Page Then click on save changes.

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a front-page.php file in your active theme folder.
It can be use for both Your latest posts or a static page as you want.

Comment: So I can put anything I want into this page and then link the wordpress pages with a simple <a href="address"></a> ?